# How to Print a Document from the Modern Library in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, sharepoint-framework, spfx-extensions

I have a certain use case of being able to print a document directly from the modern library using a button. Almost a one click solution. I had a quick look around and found ways to print a modern SharePoint page, or to print list items.

But I didn't find a way to implement this using SharePoint framework. Has anyone seen a similar solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your description, my understanding is that you want use SPFX to print sharepoint modern page. You could refer to this:

https://github.com/devscopeninjas/dvs-spfx-extensions

The extension would create floating button on the bottom of the page so you can export your page to PDF or PNG.